# Initialize child class from base definition

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Apologies if this is a commonly asked question, but I have spend quite a while googling for the answer and could not find definitive answer.

I have an abstract class that contains fields that are (definitions of) other abstract classes . Those are then used for concrete implementations of properties. However when I want to initialize implementation of that abstract class I would like those fields to be populated with particular implementations of the fields. This actually sounds confusing even for myself, so here is the example.

```
// My main abstract class
public abstract class Log
{
    public virtual bool AppendLog
    {
        set { _logWriter.Append = value; }
    }

    internal LogWriter _logWriter; //LogWriter is another abstract class

    public abstract void AddEntry(string input);
}

// Implementation of abstract class
public class SyncLog : Log
{
    public SyncLog
    {
        // Now I want to initialize LogWriter abstract class in parent with
        // It's actual implementation SyncLogWriter : LogWriter
        _logWriter = new SyncLogWriter(); 
    }

    public override void AddEntry(string input)
    {
        content.AddEntry(input);
        _logWriter.Write("Hello");
    }
}
```

While this technically complies and even works, there is a problem. When using the _logWriter I can only access the methods and properties declared in abstract class LogWriter, but not ones that are additionally implemented in it's child (SyncLogWriter). While technically it makes sense I wonder if there is any way to do the similar approach, but making all the additional stuff available in SyncLogWriter be available?

Comment: ..why have an abstract base then? Just declare your `_logWriter` variable as a `SyncLogWriter` and you're done.. ? You're attempting to bypass polymorphism here.. why not just remove it altogether?

Comment: How would you expect this to work? What if you tried to access members specific to one `LogWriter` concrete class, but you had set the field to a different one?

Comment: I can't see what LogWriter involves here, but would it be a candidate for becoming an interface? You could then have _logWriter as type ILogWriter (for example) and then call the interface methods in the abstract class implementations.

Comment: Perhaps I am going into too much abstraction here?
The whole idea behind this setup is to make the base class easily extensible and to be able to use properties which will be used by all its ancestors but have a different implementation of them.

Comment: @barrick I was thinking about this as well, might give a try once I get more comfortable with interfaces :)

Comment: The implementation details that you can abstract away are anything that isn't part of the class's public interface (by which I mean not necessarily an actual `interface` as defined in C#, but more generally the signatures of public members). Anything which is part of the public interface can't be abstracted away because the code which uses that class needs to know about it in order to use it successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an additional member `_syncLogWriter` on the inherited class `SyncLog`.
Also it is even better to initialize your `_logWriter` member for the base class through the constructor and make it private.

```
// My main abstract class
public abstract class Log
{
    protected Log(LogWriter logWriter)
    {
        _logWriter = logWriter;
    }

    public virtual bool AppendLog
    {
        set { _logWriter.Append = value; }
    }

    private LogWriter _logWriter; //LogWriter is another abstract class

    public abstract void AddEntry(string input);
}

// Implementation of abstract class
public class SyncLog : Log
{
    private SyncLogWriter _syncLogWriter

    public SyncLog() : this(new SyncLogWriter()) { }

    private SyncLog(SyncLogWriter logWriter) : base(logWriter)
    {
        _syncLogWriter = logWriter; 
    }

    public override void AddEntry(string input)
    {
        content.AddEntry(input);
        _syncLogWriter.Write("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now that you have added implementation I understood what you mean!
Looks like a solution to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a private readonly property of type `SyncLogWriter` which actually points to `_logWriter`.

```
public class SyncLog : Log
{
    public SyncLog
    {
        _logWriter = new SyncLogWriter(); 
    }

    private SyncLogWriter LogWriter
    {
        get { return (SyncLogWriter)_logWriter; }
    }

    public override void AddEntry(string input)
    {
        content.AddEntry(input);
        _logWriter.Write("Hello");
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
         LogWriter.SomeSyncLogWriterMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, a cleaner solution than the other two answers would be to use generics, as so:

```
public abstract class Log<TLogWriter> where TLogWriter : LogWriter
{
    public virtual bool AppendLog
    {
        set { _logWriter.Append = value; }
    }

    internal TLogWriter _logWriter;

    public abstract void AddEntry(string input);
}

public class SyncLog : Log<SyncLogWriter>
{
    public SyncLog
    {
        _logWriter = new SyncLogWriter(); 
    }

    public override void AddEntry(string input)
    {
        content.AddEntry(input);
        _logWriter.Write("Hello");
    }
}
```

This removes the need for duplicating fields, or casting

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with generics yet, but will read about them. The one possible issue I see here is that the LogWriter is not the only abstract class Log will be using, there are several more of the kind.

Comment: @AndreyZh. So there are a lot of abstract classes of the form `MyClass`, with inheriting class `SyncMyClass`? And all of them have public members which are in `SyncMyClass` but not `MyClass`, which `SyncLog` needs to access?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the base explanation, but it goes like this.
I am trying to make a library which will be used for logging in several other programs.
Log is an abstract class which will have multiple implementations that will be exposed to the outside world. 
There are a few other classes, that have abstract base, and a few particular implementations. LogWriter is one one of them, another for example is Format abstract class that have a couple implementations. 
The decendants of Log may need any combination of LogWriter and Format decendants.

Comment: @AndreyZh. Ah, well then any solution is going to be problematic because the number of descendants of `Log` will be equal to the product of the number of descendents of all the other base classes it uses. That goes for all three answers posted. What you really want to try to do is ensure that the descendents don't require different public interfaces. That way you can do simple polymorphism without all this difficulty.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I'm facing. Will need to think more about the overall architecture.